# ClickOnce activated in Chromium Edge - Browser still downloads deployment manifest instead of starting application

Tags: clickonce

We deploy one of our applications as a ClickOnce application. To make this work in the new Chromium based Edge browser we have had to make sure that our users either manually activate ClickOnce using edge://flags or are using a policy to enable ClickOnce in Edge. Both are described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-learn-more-co-di).

This works for most of our users but we have at least one user where this still does not make ClickOnce work. The browser still insists on downloading the deployment manifest (.application) instead of activating the ClickOnce application just as if ClickOnce was not activated.

This is the situation for this user:

- Running Windows 7.
- Have enabled ClickOnce using edge://flags.
- Made sure that the registry flags in the ClickOnce/Edge policy (see link above) is not present at all (neither under "current user" or "local machine").
- Reinstalled Chromium Edge.

My questions are:

- What else, other than the settings/policy mentioned, can make Edge behave like this?
- Are there logging/debugging facilities in Edge that can be used to troubleshoot a problem like this? I have tried the instructions [here](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) but have not been able to make it log anything that is on a level that can explain why this happens.

Comment: Same problem, even if the flag is pushed via windows policy (you have to download the template). And also from version 87 of edge, the "default" behavior of the click once flag is changed and should be equal to "enabled". See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-relnote-stable-channel .
Everything works fine on Windows 10, the problem seems related to windows 7